# Accessing a dataset map in angular2

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

I have the following:

### .html template

```
<name-view data-topic='id'></name-view>
```

### .dart component

```
import 'dart:html';

class NameView implements AfterViewInit
{
String topic;

void ngAfterViewInit( ) {

    // datset is not reference below - works in polymer-1.x attached() method
    topic = this.datset['topic'];
  }
}
```

However, the code in ngAfterViewInit does not work. 
How can I retrieve the data-topic attribute in angular2?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

Comment: Exactly Langley, and thanks. So easy to accomplish. Polymer method is easy, angular2 even improves on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make `@Input('data-topic')` work but the other ways are working

```
@Component(
    selector: 'app-element',
    template: '''
<h1>app-element</h1>
<name-view data-topic='id' topic='topicid'></name-view>
''',
    directives: const [NameView])
class AppElement {}
```

```
@Component(
  selector: 'name-view',
  template: '''
<h1>test-element</h1>
<div>data-topic: {{topic}}</div>
<div>topic: {{topic2}}</div>
<div>topicFromRef: {{topicFromRef}}</div>
''')
class NameView implements OnInit {
  @Input('data-topic')
  String topic;

  @Input('topic')
  String topic2;

  String topicFromRef;

  ElementRef _elementRef;
  TestElement(this._elementRef);

  void ngOnInit() {
    topicFromRef = (_elementRef.nativeElement as Element).dataset['topic'];
  }
}
```

Using `ElementRef` is discouraged because this prevents running the code in a WebWorker or on server rendering.